# Should I return null, an empty object or an empty array for json with no data?

Tags: jquery, json

I am sending an ajax request that will search a database. If no results are found, is there a reason to choose to return `null`, `{}` or `[]`? Is one considered "standard" or "best practice"?

Comment: What do you return if you *do* find results?

Comment: I was asking the question generically on purpose, but this particular instance would be passed to the .autofill() function _form autofill (jQuery plugin) by Creative Area_

Comment: But the answer depends on what you'd normally send back. If you normally send back an array, it wouldn't make sense to send back an empty object would it?

Comment: I see, so this isn't a "do it this way, all the time" issue. But, in either case, `null` is probably the less perferred option?

Comment: I think @Avish's answer addresses this pretty well. There might be a case for returning `null` in certain situations. If you usually return an array, and empty array is probably a good choice. But if you usually return an object, then, IMHO, null is acceptable and may be better than an empty object. If you usually return just a string or a number, then null would probably be the preferred choice.

Comment: I agree and will edit my answer to address the subtlety of when `{}` is appropriate.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

The differences are pretty negligible.

`null` is the usual way to denote "no value", but your client side code will need to explicitly check for that.

If the response actually means "here are the results, but they're empty", `[]` or `{}` might be more suitable, as long as you match the format of non-empty responses (i.e. if the client is expecting an array, don't send `{}`, and vice versa).

Basically:

- If an empty result set is a special case and you want to write explicit behavior for it, `null` seems more appropriate.
- If your client expects an array (e.g. it will loop through the results), then use `[]`.
- If your client expects a *map* of key-value pairs (e.g. it will loop through keys or will use `result[someKey]`), then use `{}`.
- If your client expects a single *object* (i.e. it expects the result to have well-known properties and will do something like `result.someProperty`), then `null` is better than returning an empty object.

Or more clearly: If the client thinks of the result as a single value, use `null`. If the client thinks of it as a list, use `[]`. If the client thinks of it as a map, use `{}`.